# Sending mail in ASP.Net connecting to SQL Server with Excel attachment

Tags: sql, asp.net, excel, email

I have two tables A and B, A has two columns "Name" and "Email address", B has many columns and rows with one column that has Name, so the relationship between these two table is the "Name", hence for 1 Name in table A there will be several rows in Table B.

What I would like to achieve is, I need a mail to be triggered to each Name in table A, with an attachment of an Excel file which will contain the respective persons data in table B. Consider table A has 100 "name" then 100 mails should be triggered to respective email address with each mail carrying its respective Excel attachment that contains the respective "Name" data from table B.

Example: Table A has `BOB` and `MIKE`

Bob will receive a mail with an Excel attachment that will show all BOB's data that is available in table B. Mike will receive a mail with an attachment that has his data in table B.

The attachment can be even displayed as a table in the mail too as there will be not more than 25 rows of data.

I already have this working in VBA in Outlook which will create an Excel file and store it in a folder, fetch a mail template, attach the Excel to the mail and have it in the outbox of the mailbox so when all the 100 mails are generated, mails start getting triggered. Now I am trying to achieve the same in ASP.Net and then automating it so that it gets executed at specific time on a specified day.

Below is the VBA code I use for the same.

```
Sub testing()

Dim OutApp As Object  
Dim OutMail As Object  
Dim i As Integer  
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rec As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim rec1 As New ADODB.Recordset  
Dim Email_ID As String  
Dim Table As String

Email_ID = ""

conn.Open "DSN=testing"

Sql = "select name,EmailAddress from Table A"

rec.Open Sql, conn

While Not rec.EOF

    Sql1 = "select name ,id ,model, stagename,date, from Table B where owneridname ='" & rec.Fields(0)&"'"

    rec1.Open Sql1, conn

    Dim ExlApp As Object

    strFldr = "C:\Data\"

    Set ExlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ExlApp.Application.Visible = False
    ExlApp.Workbooks.Add.SaveAs (strFldr & rec.Fields(0) & "Report.xlsx")
    ExlApp.Workbooks.Open strFldr & rec.Fields(0) & "Report.xlsx"
    ExlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
    ExlApp.cells(1, 1) = "Name"
    ExlApp.cells(1, 2) = "id"
    ExlApp.cells(1, 3) = "Model"
    ExlApp.cells(1, 4) = "Stagename"
    ExlApp.cells(1, 5) = "Date"
    ExlApp.cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rec1
    ExlApp.cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ExlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ExlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close
    rec1.Close
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set OutMail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Data\sampletempl\sample.oft")

    On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail

        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "Bigboss@boss.com"
        .To = rec.Fields(1)
        .CC = "Boss@boss.com"
        .Attachments.Add strFldr & rec.Fields(0) & "Report.xlsx"
        .Subject = "Report for the week"
        .Body = "Dear " & rec.Fields(0) & "," & vbCr & OutMail.Body & vbclf & Table
        .Send

    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set ExlApp = Nothing
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    rec.MoveNext
Wend

rec.Close
End Sub
```

Please help me out on this, I have separate .net code to send mail and to create Excel files but don't know how to achieve my logic.

Comment: which database server you are using ? MS-SQL?

Comment: Do you have outlook and excel installed in server you are trying to deploy your asp.net application?

Comment: I am using SQL, Yes i have oulook and Excel installed in the computer where this application is about to be deployed

Comment: Hi Please help on this request